# Is "But really you would do better to ask your teacher. They are paid to answer this kind of question." in an answer the wrong message and anti-SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

[This answer to *When can Moon occult Venus?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/46858/7982) feels to me to be the worst possible message. To me it looks like "you are wrong, you used the wrong number, here's the right number, and instead of thinking about it (as your teacher must have thought was a good idea) our seeking out advice in SE you should have pressed your teacher harder."

I think this was just plain bad in two ways:

1. To me it's clear that the teacher left the student with a *challenge*. That's great teaching! That's doing *exactly what a teacher is paid to do!*
2. Turning to Stack Exchange for assistance is excellent! There's a basic "homework question" policy in place here, we generally try to provide insight and advice how to look at a problem, and avoid just plain answering them.
3. This does the opposite. It just blurts out the answer without teaching anything (against our homework policy) and the only guidance seems to be 'you should not have asked here' after answering.

I've [added another answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/46894/7982) that provides guidance and insight how one can approach this whole class of synodic vs sidereal period problems, included links to several other related SE questions and answer where even more can be learned, and congratulated the OP for turning to Stack Exchange!

**Question:** Is "But really you would do better to ask your teacher. They are paid to answer this kind of question." in an answer the wrong message and anti-SE?

If we believe that SE is a good thing, why not promote good use of it at every turn?